# Change Chinese characters directories to English characters directories in Cygwin

Tags: windows, git, cygwin

I installed the Cygwin, it generated the Chinese directory:

[image]

You see the `离人酒巷@lenova-pc` and the `pwd` shows `/home/离人酒巷/deep/`

Can I change the Chinese characters to English characters? or if is trouble, whether I can create a English character user?

Answer (score 0):

You can remap the windows user to an a new name for cygwin
using  `/etc/passwd`.

https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/ntsec.html#ntsec-mapping-passwdinfo

```
$ mkpasswd -c > /etc/passwd
```

The file `/etc/passwd` has the user fields separated by `:`
Change the first `WindowsUser` and the sixth `/home/WindowsUser` to the new name. Close cygwin and restart the terminal.